# What should I look towards to create an easily maintainable news page?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a news page on my website but I cant figure out how I should make it easily manageable.

The idea would be to have the latest news appear at the top and for it to knock the older news further down as new news is added.

Someone mentioned mySQL, had a little look but seemed quite complicated for what I want to do.

Really old news would go into a drop down menu, so to save space/loading etc

[image]

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that given you've just tagged HTML and CSS and you obviously aren't using a database that this is a basic hand coded site.

If you aren't going to use a database (honestly this is probably the right approach) you're at least going to need a dynamic language, the easiest to accomplish it would be PHP.

This is the kind of thing that CMS's like WordPress do right out of the box. CMS is Content Management System, and your news page is exactly that.

It would be relatively quick and painless to write for even a moderate PHP developer. If you didn't want to use a database (you should) you could load flat documents then create each news article as it's own document. Parsing the creation date and sorting, then relegating to a dropdown is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a database and a server-side programming language.

HTML and CSS just format what the website looks like, they don't possess the capability to store and retrieve data under certain conditions.

PHP is one such example of a server-side language. While I don't think PHP is a very good language, it's kind of the best in the world for teaching beginners because it puts into context the logic of what's happening by making you deliberately write it out. Other ways of making web applications like Ruby on Rails aren't so good because they're based on the premise of following conventions and automatically generating groups of files for you, what you're actually doing might only come into context much later down the road.

MySQL is a Structured Query Language and it's used to query information, most usually from databases. You'll need to use an SQL in some regard in conjunction with your server-side language.

Look up some tutorials on creating databases and querying information from them, preferably starting out with a language like PHP. This will probably be under a title like "Create a news website".